# Link in a cell of Free Jqgrid

Tags: html, hyperlink, jqgrid, cell

I am trying to generate a link inside a cell:

the source code of the cell is the following:

```
echo '<row id="' . $obj['id'] . '">';
echo $obj['name_file']?'<cell>'.'<![CDATA['.'<a href="../'.$path.$obj['name_file'].'" target="_blank">Visit</a>'.']]>'.'</cell>':'<cell></cell>';
echo '</row>';
```

With above versions of Jqgrid the source code written worked, but this new version It does not work and I don´t find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom formatter since it allows for any kind of link.  See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
        function htmlTest() {

            htmlTest.prototype.display = function(){  
                $("#grid").jqGrid({
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "firstName" },
                        { name: "lastName", formatter:this.htmlFormatter}
                    ],
                    data: [
                        { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
                        { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
                        { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
                        { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
                        { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
                    ]
                    }

                );
            };

            htmlTest.prototype.htmlFormatter = function( cellvalue, options, rowObject ) {
                var id = options.rowId;
                var something = "blabla";
                return "<a href='http://someurl.com?id=" + id + "&something=" + something + "' target='yourTargetWindow'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
            };

        };


        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myTest = new htmlTest();
            myTest.display();
        });    
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```